# Why don't I see new apache2 access log messages for a (wsgi) request?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server, logging, mod-wsgi

This week I installed a simple Ubuntu 14.04 server on which I host a new website (which I built with [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)). The website works fine without any problems.

I now wanted to check out the access log, in which I expect every request which is made to be recorded. So I do a `tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log` which currently shows this (x-ed away my own ip-address):

```
212.xx.xx.xx - - [08/Jul/2015:18:42:05 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3594 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0"
212.xx.xx.xx - - [08/Jul/2015:18:42:05 +0000] "GET /icons/ubuntu-logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 3688 "http://52.28.183.18/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0"
212.xx.xx.xx - - [08/Jul/2015:18:42:06 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 501 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0"
212.xx.xx.xx - - [08/Jul/2015:18:42:06 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 501 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0"
```

This seems to be the request I made two days ago (when I installed the server) which opened up the Apache Ubuntu default welcome page. The problem is that I don't see any new requests recorded. Could it be that these are recorded somewhere else because the website works through mod_wsgi?

All tips are welcome!

[EDIT]

My website config looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
         WSGIDaemonProcess mywebsite
     WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mywebsite/app.wsgi

     <Directory /var/www/mywebsite>
            WSGIProcessGroup mywebsite
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: How is your Apache site configuration set up? Do you have a `CustomLog` directive in there?

Comment: @bertieb - No, nothing special in that. I used the most simple setup I could find on the internet. I'll add it to the question in a second.

Comment: I think you might be right in your supposition about something else handling access logs, per [this mailing list message](http://librelist.com/browser/flask/2012/8/10/standard-request-logging-not-error-logging/#e83bf5398d242ea628bba3effaaa0e37). It is possible to make flask handle them though: [1](https://docstrings.wordpress.com/2014/04/19/flask-access-log-write-requests-to-file/) [2](https://docstrings.wordpress.com/2014/04/19/flask-access-log-write-requests-to-file/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, turns out I didn't have logging set up in apache. I added this to mywebsite.config:

```
LogLevel info
ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/access.log" combined
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been trying to track down an issue for hours and just adding "LogLevel info" to my site conf made my life a lot easier.